# What temperament did the akonting players use when they jammed with Béla Fleck?

Tags: temperament, banjo, african

In the album and film ["Throw Down Your Heart"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Acoustic_Planet,_Vol._3:_Africa_Sessions), Béla Fleck (banjo) and Jil Ekona Jatta (akonting) jam ([video](https://youtu.be/sJt6jn0xT8A?t=3183)). The banjo is fretted and the akonting is not. How did this work? Here are a few possible answers I can think of:

- Akonting is played in equal temperament
- Akonting isn't usually played in equal temperament, but Jatta knows hand positions for different temperaments and adjusted.
- The music is out of tune and I couldn't tell
- Béla Fleck did something to adjust to the Akonting temperament, such as avoiding the notes that would be the most dissonant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s closest to your third bullet in the sense that they didn’t really change how they play exactly, so they are playing in two different temperaments, in a way. But there’s a little bit of the fourth bullet in there.

This actually isn’t as unusual as you might think. A piano concerto presents a similar problem, although less extreme. Three things happen that make it work, and I hear evidence of all three in the linked video:

1. There is a slight adjustment of some pitches by one of both players
2. The notes played by Bela Flek are selected carefully to fit best with the tuning of the akonting
3. Our ears quickly grow acclimated to the tuning difference

The third point happens in many areas of music. Synthesizers, pianos, and guitars are actually tuned slightly differently, but our ears both adjust quickly and are also used to it from a lifetime of hearing the combination.